# как получить список Assembly из нужного процесса

Tags: c#, .net, assembly

Как получить список Assembly из стороннего процесса?

Comment: Что значит «из нужного процесса»? Вы имеете в виду, из _не своего_ процесса?

Comment: @VladD - получить нужный процесс по имени и уже в из него получить список Assembly - процесс нужен запущен!

Comment: Получить процесс по имени просто: `GetProcessesByName`. Интересна нетривиальная часть.

Comment: Обязательно в виде чистого кода на C#? Варианты в виде вызова cdb/sos с последующим парсингом вывода подойдут?

Comment: @PashaPash я не знаю что за cdb/sos - мне просто нужно на форму добавить 1 combo box с процессами - далее выбираю нужный и нажимаю кнопку узнать - и нужно получить все Assembly из выбранного процесса

Comment: @Azymok для этого вам придется программно прицепить отладчик к тому процессу, из которого вы хотите получить список - или готовый отладчик, cdb/windbg, или самописный - т.е. лезть в выбранный процесс через интерфейс ICorDebug. Оба варианта достаточно сложны в реализации, особенно на обычном C#, так что выбор зависит от того, что вы дальше с этим списком хотите делать. Сорри, нет возможности сейчас написать полноценный ответ :(

Comment: Посмотрите, например https://github.com/anvaka/slinject/tree/master/Src/slinject/Debugger - это готовая обертка. Сборки в ней называются DebugModules

Comment: @PashaPash просто получить список - максимум записать в текстовый файл.А может можно как то заинжектить dll с НУЖНОЙ функцией в процесс?

Comment: @Azymok инжект - это совершенно другой вопрос :) хотя он по ссылке выше тоже решен

Comment: @PashaPash вы можете открыть чат?Нужно кое что уточнить

Answer (score 1):

Для NET 3.5 и более ранних версий можно получить список сборок через свойство *Process.Modules*:

```
Process pr=Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv")[0];
var x = pr.Modules;//получение списка модулей

/*Для каждой управляемой DLL в списке будет ее Native Image - файл "*.ni.dll"*/

foreach (ProcessModule y in x)
{
    if (y.ModuleName.EndsWith("ni.dll"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(y.ModuleName.Replace(".ni.dll",".dll"));
    }
}
```

В NET 4.0 и более поздних версиях механизм загрузки сборок был изменен, так что не для всех грузится Native Image через *LoadLibrary* и, соответственно, не все они появятся в списке модулей. Для получения полного списка сборок можно использовать библиотеку [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd):

```
public string GetProcessAssemblies(Process pr)
{
        int pid = pr.Id;

        DataTarget dt;

        //присоединяемся к процессу
        using (dt = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(pid, 5000, AttachFlag.Passive))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(600);

            //получаем загруженные версии CLR
            foreach (ClrInfo clrVersion in dt.ClrVersions)
            {
                string s = clrVersion.TryGetDacLocation();
                var runtime = dt.CreateRuntime(s);

                sb.AppendLine("CLR " + clrVersion.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine();

                //получаем список модулей для данной версии CLR
                foreach (ClrModule module in runtime.EnumerateModules())
                {
                    if (module.IsFile)
                        sb.AppendLine(module.Name);
                }
                sb.AppendLine();

            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }           

}
```

Источник: [Steve Horne - Enumerating all Modules in a Managed Process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsvc/2015/12/16/enumerating-all-modules-in-a-managed-process/)

Comment: Круто! А почему никто не плюсует?